# Alternative to sudo which allows regular expressions

Tags: linux, regex

Up to now sudo only allows simple wildcards. See: https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html#Wildcards

Is there an alternative or an replacement which allows regular expressions?

If possible Python compatible regular expression :-)

Here one example:

This line should allow to start/restart apache for user `bob`

```
bob ALL = NOPASSWD: (/usr)?/bin/systemctl (start|restart|status) apache2(.service)?
```

`(/usr)?`: On some systems the systemctl binary has a different path :-(

`(start|restart|status)`: These systemctl command should be allowed for Bob.

`apache2(.service)?`: The ".service" is optional and if I type the command interactively, than I am lazy and don't want to type more characters than necessary.

My current work-around is to create severals lines in the sudo config via configuration management.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260435 (goes to https://gitlab.com/edneville/please) is a thing, but do think thrice before trusting some newfangled program to the job of guarding root permissions!